# Grails 3 accessing node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, grails, gradle

Starting on a Grails 3 app and trying to use a node plugin. My custom javascript is located under `grails-app/assets/javascripts` but when I run `gradle build` it installs the `node_modules` folder under my root project directory. This folder has all my JS libraries and I'm unable to access them from my within `grails-app/assets/javascripts`.

Is there a way to install `node_modules` under `grails-app`? Do I need to specify the directory in my `build.gradle`?

Here's my node and grunt plugins in my `build.gradle`.

`classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.12"
 classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.12"`

`apply plugin:"com.moowork.node"
 apply plugin:"com.moowork.grunt"`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the location of the node_modules folder.

First, upgrade the node and grunt plugins to version 0.13

```
classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:0.13"
classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-grunt-plugin:0.13"
```

Second, add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
node { nodeModulesDir = file("grails-app") }
```

This will create the node_modules folder under grails-app (i.e. grails-app/node_modules)

Comment: Still does not work. I updated my plugins and rebuilt, but it still created `node_modules` under root directory.

Comment: `node {
    nodeModulesDir = file("grails-app")
}`